# Show the content of the function in the div

Tags: javascript, html

How do I show myFunction content in `myDiv` div? So show "Example"?

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Example!";
}
```

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;    
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Close your p tag. `<p id="demo"</p>`. Where are you calling your function?

Comment: Typo: "<p> id="demo"</p>"  should be "<p id="demo"></p>" (there's also a typo in the previous comment, so I write this once more...)

Comment: @Johannes There's no typo in my comment. That's the original code the OP posted

Comment: I want to show the word "Example" in the div

Comment: @j08691 Ah sorry, I misunderstood that! In the  edited version of the question which I saw when writing that, the code was still different (and also wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
<div class="myDiv">
<p> id="demo"</p>
</div>
```

Should be this:

```
<div class="myDiv">
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

With the `id` tag inside `<p>`

And this:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Example!";
}
```

Should also get called since it is a function and not just the `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Example!";`

Example 1:

```
function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Example!";
    }
myFunction();
```

```js
function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Example!";
    }
    
myFunction();
```

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;    
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Example 2:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Example!";
```

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Example!";
```

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;    
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: ok correct.. But I want to show the word "Example" in the div

Comment: Now run the function by calling it in the Javascript with myFunctions(); on a new line

Comment: I need you to show me, also by updating your answer. I'm a beginner

Comment: I tried. But I get a blank div

Comment: I have tried with the function and it works. Put the function to choose it as a useful answer. If I pass a parameter in myFuntion, when I call it the second time do I always have to pass it the parameter?

Comment: I expanded my answer further, hope this helps you learn this process over all. Happy coding

Comment: Last thing. If I passed a parameter how should I behave?

Comment: Check out this link that explains it a bit more https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Comment: And this one goes into a bit more complex example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this just by using the `getElementById` no need for a function.

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Example!";
```

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 5px outset red;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <p id="demo"><p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you are not clear about the concept of html,CSS and js.myDiv is a CSS class.You can beatify the class in it.Whatever html tag uses that class will integrate the proper of .myDiv class. myFunction() is a js function if you use the demo id in your html tag and it will act according to your function defination.